# Email form fields array

Tags: php, arrays, email

Who can i create an array with email form fields array.

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $content=array(
        $name=$this->strip_tags($_POST['name']),
        $email=$this->strip_tags($_POST['email']),
        $phone=$this->strip_tags($_POST['phone']),
        $address=$this->strip_tags($_POST['address']),
        $city=$this->strip_tags($_POST['city']),
        $subject=$this->strip_tags($_POST['subject']),
        $message=$this->strip_tags($_POST['message'])
        );
```

and then send it using  the mail function.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The proper syntax to create an array uses `array('key' => $value`) , not `array($key = $value)` as you have here (which works, but doesn't produce the result you probably expect).  Why do you want it in an array to `mail()` it? You would then need to pull each value back out to display it in your message body.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do this, which is a lot easier:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$to = "someone@example.com"; // send email to
$from = "Your Name <you@example.com>"; // send email from
$subject = "Form submitted"; // email subject
$body = "The form has been submitted!

Here's the form data that was submitted.

Name: ".$_POST['name']."
Email: ".$_POST['email']."
Phone: ".$_POST['phone']."
Address: ".$_POST['address']."
City: ".$_POST['city']."
Subject: ".$_POST['subject']."

Message:

".$_POST['message']."

Some other text under the form data here...";

$email = mail($to, $subject, $body, "From: $from");

if($email) { // you don't actually need this, it's just to make sure it sends :)
echo "Email sent successfully";
}

}
```

This will send an email with the form data submitted.

I hope this helps!